# Route port through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, iptables

I have an udp server running on a dedicated server. It listens on port 5005. One client (Client1) in my LAN is connected to that dedicated server via OpenVPN and can talk to that udp server through the VPN.

Two other Clients of my LAN need access to that udp server too. Now I want my client1 to route traffic incoming on port 5005 through the vpn to my udp server.

I thought this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 5005 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:5005
```

+

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

will do the job, but unfortunately I am not able to talk to the udp server.

Comment: Port forwarding is just one part of the puzzle. There are two additional concerns: Traffic needs to be directed to “client1” for any processing to happen at all. Your server needs to be able to send the response message. It most likely doesn’t have a route to “client1”’s local network so the response will be lost.

Comment: @DanielB I thought when using an UDP server there is no need for a response

Comment: UDP doesn’t imply one-way communication. It may or may not be that way here.

Comment: @DanielB Okay, but the problem here is that the UDP sever does not receive anything at all when I send it to Client1:5005

Comment: @DanielB It doesn't need to have a route to the local network; it just needs a route to client1, since client1 is doing NAT.

Comment: It does DNAT, which replaces the destination. The source remains unchanged. Just like port forwarding on your router.